# How do I get the prices from grouped products' s children?

Tags: price

this is my code, but I don't know how to continue this :

```
$id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId(); //grouped product id

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the simple products associated to the grouped product like this:

```
$associated = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
        ->getAssociatedProducts($product);
```

Then loop through them and get their price:

```
foreach ($associated as $simple) {
    $price = $simple->getFinalPrice();
    //do something with $price
}
```